# Minicart.js - Items are added to cart but cart not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, minicart

I have a click function on a button that adds an item to my cart using the Minicart.js library from minicartjs.com. When the button is clicked items are being added to the cart however, the cart is not  popping up as expected. I've tested this on up to date versions of Chrome and IE (IE 11).

Some things I've noticed:

- In the debugger if I execute the show cart function
  `paypal.minicart.view.show()` the cart displays fine. Even with the
  items I've added.
- When my add button is clicked "class" is appended to the body with no
  actual class assigned:

[image: Chrome debugger showing body tag with class and ppminicart div]

- When the cart *is* showing a class "minicart-showing" is appended to
  the body.

The following script is at the end of a MVC partial View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/minicart.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".showcart").click(function () {
        var data = $(this).attr("data-id");   
        paypal.minicart.cart.add(JSON.parse(data));
        // $("#body").toggleClass("minicart-showing"); <---doesn't work
        // paypal.minicart.view.show() <---- doesn't work
    });
paypal.minicart.render();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After further reviewing the minicartjs examples in the author's repository. I found that using `e.stopPropagation()` within the click function resolves the issue.

```
   $(".showcart").click(function (e) { // <--- added the e function
    var data = $(this).attr("data-id");
    e.stopPropagation(); // <--- And this line.
    paypal.minicart.cart.add(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

[Code Example From Author's GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jeffharrell/minicart/blob/master/examples/customclick.html)